# Remove unwanted shortcut gnome classic

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

On ubuntu 11.10 using gnome classic I accidently made an error and now I have to deal with a redirect button to the gnome tweak tool in the top bar of the gnome interface, right next to the locations button.(but can be moved accros the top bar) I don't want and can't delete the button. Is there a solution to get rid of it?

Answer (score 17):

To remove this icon, <kbd>alt</kbd>+right-click on the icon and click remove in the menu.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the rationale behind not showing the remove option in response to a normal right click? This is the most absurdly user unfriendly 'feature' I've seen in awhile. How the heck are you supposed to discover it without Google?

Comment: @JosephGarvin I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: @JosephGarvin My understanding is that if you don't hold down the `Alt` key, mouse input on a panel applet is interpreted by the applet itself. Holding down `Alt` makes the panel interpret the input. So, for example, if you had an applet that showed a special applet-specific menu on right-click, you'd right-click without `Alt` to show that menu, but you'd right-click with `Alt` to show the generic menu that shows options like removing the applet altogether.

Comment: Never-the-less I've made this mistake a few times - seems like it's a UI feature designed by a technically minded person rather than someone who has humans in mind

Comment: That's very unintuitive.

Answer (score 16):

Now it's `Windows+Alt+rightclick` (a.k.a. `Super+Alt+rightclick`) [as described here](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/04/how-to-remove-icons-displayed-on-top.html).  In a few years, it'll be `shift+ctrl+super+alt+numlock+middleclick`.

Comment: Haha +1 for being right _and_ funny :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's compiz that add the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key to the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Rightclick combination. You can test this by killing it. Compiz needs <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Rightclick for something else apparently.

Gnome classic session: <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Rightclick

Gnome classic session, no effects: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Rightclick